# Visual Studio - Pre- and post-build execution locations

Tags: visual-studio, group-policy, pre-build-event

Is there a way to change the location of the path in which Visual Studio 2015 executes the pre- and post-build events?

In my company there was a change in the Group Policy, so pre- and post-build events are resulting in the following error message:

> This program is blocked by group policy. For more information, contact your system administrator.

This is because the new group policy prevents cmds from running out of the USER-folder.

Any idea of how to resolve this without running Visual Studio as an administrator or changing the Group Policy?

Comment: its in the msbuild project file. you can specify the path. i would suggest asking your IT department to make changes/accommodations

Comment: Do you know where I can find the reference for changing the path via the msbuild project file?

Comment: look in your csproj or other project type. its a text file.

Comment: I know that this is a text file. But I cant find the xml-Element which helps me to execute this. I tried do use Exec https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8zx72cd.aspx with the WorkingDirectory-Property, but this also executes the cmd from the user directory...The problem is this line: "The Exec task calls cmd.exe instead of directly invoking a process. "

Comment: Other question: what are you calling in the events? if it's just `xcopy` and friends you could also move to a plain msbuild version

Comment: What do you mean by a "plain msbuild version"?...I dont exactly know what is called in these events. For my part, I only use xcopy, but there are several other projects which obviously have the same problem...

Comment: `This is because the new group policy prevents cmds from running out of the USER-folder.`---Do you mean that the new group policy **only** allow you to use the CMDs from the USER- folder? But you said in the comment `but this also executes the cmd from the user directory...`, it makes me confused. I afraid you should contact your IT department  to make sure the real Group Policy that's blocking you.

Comment: @Leo Liu-MSFT: What confuses you? This might be a language problem so once again: The new group policy is stopping cmd-Files from starting out of the %user directory. When Visual Studio tries to do a pre- or post-build event (or a Exec task) it creates a .cmd file in %User-Directory and executes it. So the group policy says no and the build fails.

Comment: Since you could not running Visual Studio as an administrator or changing the Group Policy, how about using copy task instead of copy command in the build event, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3e54c37h.aspx?

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, you can run your Visual Studio as Administrator

Comment: The question was: "Any idea of how to resolve this without running Visual Studio as an administrator or changing the Group Policy?"